# Smoothness of the incicence correspondence associated to the join of two varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, smoothness

Let $Y\subseteq X\subsetneq\mathbb{P}^{N}$ be smooth projective varieties, and let 
$$
S_{X,Y}=\overline{\{(x,y,z)\in X\times Y\times \mathbb{P}^{N}:x\neq y, z\in\langle x,y\rangle\}}.
$$
Can we deduce the smoothness of $S_{X,Y}$ from the smoothness of $X,Y$?

I don't know theorems about the behaviour of smoothness under morphisms, but it could be easy if we knew any, via considering the projection
$$
S_{X,Y}\rightarrow X\times Y.
$$
(Notice that the fiber of every $p=(x,y)\in X\times Y$ such that $x\neq y$ is a line, and the fiber of the points $p=(y,y)\in X\times Y$ is isomorphic to $T_{y}X$).

Comment: Usually, it is not smooth. For the simplest example take $X$ to be a twisted cubic curve and $Y$ a point on it. Then $S_{X,Y}$ is a quadratic cone with vertex at this point.

Comment: It looks like your $S_{X, Y}$ is a $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle over $Y$ times the blowup of $X$ along $Y$, and hence is smooth.

Comment: @Sasha I see that the image of $S_{X,Y}$ under the projection to $\mathbb{P}^{N}$ is a cone. How do we know that $S_{X,Y}$ is a cone too?

Comment: @JosuaJones: Sorry, I misread your question. Your $S_{X,Y}$ is indeed, a $P^1$-bundle over the blowup of $Y \times X$ in the graph of the embedding $Y \to X$ (almost as Piotr Achinger said). In fact, you could first ask this question about $X = Y = P^n$. What you get will be a $P^1$-bundle over the blowup of $P^n \times P^n$ in the diagonal. And then you can base change to $X \times Y \subset P^n \times P^n$.

Comment: @Sasha Ok, thank you! I'd appreciate if you could give me an idea how to show that it is a $\mathbb{P}^{1}$ bundle over that blow-up. Why does it imply that it is smooth? (I am not used to work with projective bundles, sorry)

Comment: @JoshuaJones: A $P^1$-bundle, by definition, is a smooth morphism with fiber $P^1$, so if its base is smooth, the total space is smooth as well. To show that the closure you are interested in is a $P^1$-bundle, you can construct an embedding from such a $P^1$-bundle to the product $X \times Y \times P^n$ and to show that its open part is the variety whose closure you consider.